# Translate relational db into couchDB (noSQL)

Tags: database, node.js, couchdb, structure

I'm currently developing a web chat with NodeJS & socket.io. 
I need some help to translate some relational database structure into NoSQL. I'm very new to the NoSQL world that's why I'm asking this here.

**My goal is to store users and the rooms they are registered in so I can list all users that are in a specific room.**

In SQL I would have done something like this:

```
--Users
John        
Jack        
James       

--Room
Javascript
PHP
CSS

--Relation
Jack  |  PHP
Jack  |  CSS
John  |  PHP
James | Javascript
```

and then `select user from relation where room like 'PHP'`

How do I actually do this using couchDB?
I need to store, list and delete.
Users are unique, room too but a user can be in multiples rooms.
When a user disconnects, he should be removed everywhere.
If a user left a room he should be removed from that room.
How do I select all users in room "PHP"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should persist the information in a database. The rooms should be a key in memory that contain an array of user id's. When a user enters a room push the item to array and pop it when he leaves. Still to illustrate some concepts here is what you can do with couchdb

Create documents like so

```
 {
     "user" : "scope77",
      "room" : "php"
}
```

Now since you want to get all users by the room they are in create a view that indexes the user by the room like so

```
    function(doc){
   if(doc.room)
   emit(doc.room,doc)
}
```

Now calls to this view will return a list of users in the particular room.

`curl http://localhost:5984/db_name/design_name/view_name?key="php"`

That's it. One thing to remember here is that in the relational model you probably would have created separate tables for rooms and users and referenced them to make the data normalized. In couch db although you can link the documents it is often easier and even preferred to have duplicate and denormalized data.

So even though you could have created a separate document for room it is far better to store the room name with the user document.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes i was thinking first of saving that into memory, but i had into some troubles with key indexing. Because i need to search for username and rooms.. If i use rooms as key, i cannot remove a user when he disconnects, because i must search in all rooms keys. But maybe i'm thinking the wrong way